# Move view from one GroPoint to other

Tags: android, animation, view, android-mapview

My MapView contains child view added by addView() with LayoutParams:

```
new MapView.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, geoPoint, 0, 0, MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM | MapView.LayoutParams.LEFT)
```

I can get screen point of my view:

```
Point p1 = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoint, null);
```

When geoPoint changes I remove all childs of mapView and then add my view with new LayoutParams (based on new geoPoint) and get new on screen point:

```
Point p2 = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(newGeoPoint, null);
```

Now I need to translate view from p1 to p2, I try:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, p1.x, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, p2.x, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, p1.y, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, p2.y);
animation.setDuration(1500);
myView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Animation plays but from wrong point to wrong point.

How can I make correct translate animation from p1 to p2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, p1.x - p2.x, 0, p1.y - p2.y);
animation.setDuration(1500);
myView.startAnimation(animation);
```

And finally do not forget to set your point's new position, otherwise it'll turn back to ex position when animation is finished.

Comment: I add view in new position before animation, I change constructor new TranslateAnimation(p1.x - p2.x, 0, p1.y - p2.y, 0);  all works!